# Como inserir um jTabbedPane dentro de um jPanel de outra classe

Tags: java

Como posso adicionar um JtabbedPane de uma classe, num jPanel de outra classe? É possível?

Na classe 'ConfEmpresa' criei um container e adicionei-lhe o JtabbedPane que se chama 'jTabConfEmpresa'.

```
public class ConfEmpresa extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static Container ct;    

public ConfEmpresa() throws SQLException {
    ct.add(jTabConfEmpresa);
}
```

Agora na classe 'Configuracoes' quero mostrar esse 'jTabConfEmpresa' através de uma ação de um botão:

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

     jPanelPrincipal.add(ConfEmpresa.ct.getComponent(0));
     jPanelPrincipal.setVisible(true);  
}
```

Quando carrego no botão para mostrar essa JTabbedPane dá o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Podias detalhar mais a tua pergunta? No mesmo Jframe ou quando passas de um jframe para outro? e postar algum código também ajuda...

Comment: Eu tenho um jTabbedPane criado numa Frame da classe 'ConfEmpresa'. Agora gostava de ao clicar num botão já criado na frame da classe 'Configuracoes' me mostrasse o jTabbedPane da classe 'ConfEmpresa', num jPanel da classe 'Configuracoes'. Fui explícito?  jPanelPrincipal.add(ConfEmpresa.jTabConfEmpresa);

Comment: Hugo, por favor, prefira [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar detalhes e formatar código propriamente. Confira o guia [ask] para reverter esses votos negativos.

Comment: Já editei a pergunta, vejam lá se está mais explícito aquilo que pretendo. Desculpem mas sou novo nestas andanças.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onde você instanciou `Container ct`?

De acordo com o que você disse, o problema esta aqui:

```
jPanelPrincipal.add(ConfEmpresa.ct.getComponent(0));
```

`ct.getComponent(0)` é nulo, pois provavelmente não está instanciado.

Comment: Mas o confEmpresa.ct não contém já o JTabbedPane que eu quero?

tenho de instanciá-lo? ao instanciá-lo não perco o JTabbedPane que está dentro?

já consegui :) Obrigado a todos pela ajuda !!!

Comment: Compartilhe a soluço.

Answer (score 1):

Sinceramente ainda nao percebi bem qual o uso do que estás a tentar fazer.

Mas tenta algo deste genero:

```
public class ConfEmpresa extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static Container ct = new Container();
public JTabbedPane jtab; 

public ConfEmpresa() throws SQLException {
    jtab=jTabConfEmpresa;
    ct.add(jTabConfEmpresa);
}
public JTabbedPane getjTab(){
     return jtab;
}
```

depois no outro `frame`:

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     // verifica se ConfEmpresa está instanciado
     jPanelPrincipal.add(ConfEmpresa.getjTab());
     jPanelPrincipal.setVisible(true);  
}
```

Não sei se deu para perceber a ideia mas acho que é este o caminho que deves seguir...